# Can not read property picture of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, vuejs2

I have the following JSON

```
{
  "error": false,
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Jagadesha NH",
    "email": "example@gmail.com",
    "phone": "9986XXXXXX",
    "dob": "1991-06-01",
    "gender": "m",
    "active": 1,
    "created_at": "2017-02-19 21:33:04",
    "updated_at": "2017-02-19 21:33:04",
    "profile": {
      "id": 1,
      "user_id": 1,
      "picture": "https:\/\/placehold.it\/150x150",
      "about": null,
      "occupation": null,
      "created_at": "2017-02-19 21:33:04",
      "updated_at": "2017-02-19 21:33:04"
    }
  },
  "msg": ""
}
```

every time I try to read picture property I get an error saying

> cannot read property picture of undefined

I am reading like

```
data.profile.picture
```

Comment: if this is the response from server you have to show us your js function which call  the server

Comment: Can you please check if the "json" is on json format or still on string format?

Comment: you need to prepend `data.profile.picture` with the name of your `object` and a `dot` notation. That is, `your_object.data.profile.picture`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it like this :

```js
var x={
  "error": false,
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Jagadesha NH",
    "email": "example@gmail.com",
    "phone": "9986xxxxxx",
    "dob": "1904-06-01",
    "gender": "m",
    "active": 1,
    "created_at": "2017-02-19 21:33:04",
    "updated_at": "2017-02-19 21:33:04",
    "profile": {
      "id": 1,
      "user_id": 1,
      "picture": "https:\/\/placehold.it\/150x150",
      "about": null,
      "occupation": null,
      "created_at": "2017-02-19 21:33:04",
      "updated_at": "2017-02-19 21:33:04"
    }
  },
  "msg": ""
}
;

alert(x.data.profile.picture);
```

if you store json in a variable access it with variable and then using dot(`<<variable_name>>.data.profile.picture`)

Comment: @Rajesh  Unless of course he has another var called `data`,  we maybe need the OP to create a working demo.

Comment: yes above snippet is working fine .. feedback from @jaghesha is pending ?

Answer (score 0):

**you are getting error because data is itself a key or property of object**

```
var a = //Your json

    a.data.profile.picture
```